# Canadian conservatives on climate change: other examples of a mainstream political party deliberately moving itself out of the Overton Window?

Tags: political-theory, history, canada

(The [Overton window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overton_window) can be thought of as "what's politically sellable to the public")

Canadian Conservative leader [O'Toole has been jettisoned by his peers](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-60236191), 73 out 119.

> Canada's Conservative MPs have voted to oust Erin O'Toole as party leader after only 18 months in the job.
>
> On Wednesday, 73 of the 119 Conservative parliamentarians voted to replace the man who led the party to defeat in last year's election.
>
> The Ontario Tory, who is widely viewed as a moderate, was accused of not being hardline enough after campaigning as a "true blue" conservative.

This was apparently after [some tussle about climate change](https://www.ctvnews.ca/politics/i-m-in-charge-o-toole-brushes-off-conservative-grassroots-vote-on-climate-change-1.5358761) being accepted onto the party platform, even in a [fairly watered down fashion](https://nationalpost.com/news/politics/otoole-declares-the-debate-is-over-on-climate-change-but-his-partys-grassroots-disagree).

> On Friday night, O’Toole gave a keynote speech to the convention promising his party will put forward a serious environment plan. “We cannot ignore the reality of climate change,” O’Toole said. “The debate is over.”
>
> But the next day, it was announced that the 3,100 voting delegates at the convention had narrowly rejected a resolution to add language into the party’s policy book saying that: “We recognize that climate change is real. The Conservative Party is willing to act.”

**Did Europe see anything like that in the past, either on the left or the right?  Coming from a *large* party adopting a hard ideological stance on a particular subject, at odds with the electorate at large.  Loss after loss, i.e. not misjudging one election and then failing to correct later, but persisting.**

For the last 2 elections, the Conservatives, under Scheer (also ousted) and O'Toole have performed credibly, *[within their natural constituencies](https://www.ctvnews.ca/politics/federal-election-2021/interactive-how-canadians-voted-in-the-past-7-federal-elections-1.5553874)*.  They won most of the Prairies and rural areas, but they it's hard to see how they could win the big-population urbanized provinces of Quebec Ontario and British Columbia, leaving only Alberta as a large prize.

Signed-up Conservative Party members are, understandably, frustrated with neither men having had a breakthrough, despite some political headwinds for the Liberals.  But it's hard to see how that could happen with their current platform, *unless the Liberals collaborated in handing them a major scandal to work with*.

If they do not win a majority outright, they'd have to try to form a coalition, but their stance on climate change will make them unacceptable to any other parties.  And that position would likely drive other parties (NDP, Liberals) together to form a coalition to keep Conservatives from governing as the biggest party, but without a formal coalition.  For the rest, their socially conservative policies may be off-putting to other parties, but they are not *that* irreconcilable for the most part and it's not like the Liberals have no skeletons in their closet.

It's also not like Canadians are that great at cutting emissions, but at least we like to pretend we care.  The Conservatives wouldn't necessarily have to do *a lot*, in fact they'd probably be voted out if they did, but they'd benefit from going through the motions publicly.

So it strange to see the Conservatives double down on climate change minimization, as it is likely costing them any chance to gain more widespread acceptance.  Yes, Canadians elected Harper but that was a) after 12 years of Liberals running the country, b) before it was known how much "political vetting" of climate change science was going to take place under Harper and c) before repeat seasons of wildfires and other climate-attributed disasters.

True-blue voters don't have much alternatives - [the People's Party is pretty self-limiting with 0 seats](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-58573878) - to voting Conservative so moving to the center should hold out the premise of winning votes while not losing too many.

This is also at odds with the position of say the British Conservative Party on climate change - it just doesn't seem like a good battle to fight *if* you want to gain power here. The calculations may be different in other places, say Australia, but it all depends on how seriously the electorate takes climate change.

> Overton described a spectrum from "more free" to "less free" with regard to government intervention, oriented vertically on an axis, to avoid comparison with the left/right political spectrum.[8] As the spectrum moves or expands, an idea at a given location may become more or less politically acceptable. After Overton's death, his Mackinac Center for Public Policy colleague Joseph Lehman further developed the idea and named it after Overton.[9]

p.s. An example here doesn't have to be about climate but it has to involve a party which had been elected before, not a fringe party remaining fringe.

Comment: The German right populist/ right wing AfD party has a questioning stance on man made climate change. However they already are a political pariah due to their stance on immigration, so their opinions on climate change don't matter much for their chances at political power.

Comment: "unless the Liberals collaborated in handing them a major scandal to work with." You mean like the WE charity? Or Lavalin? Or Lavalin again? Don't even need to go as far as Trudeau breaking ethics rules or the blackface thing. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_scandals_in_Canada  The real scandal is how far in the tank the media in Canada is. But then, it's tough to get somebody to understand something that his income depends on him *not* understanding.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_Periodical_Fund

Comment: @Dan Yes, I do mean like those.  But, if you noticed, they were **not** major enough to hand the Cons a victory - esp considering there are other parties to vote for.  I at least attribute this largely to climate change - few independents are willing to vote for them with that position. Which plays right into my question:  when did we see parties insist on pursuing a thoroughly unpopular position, costing them elections on repeat?  How did that end?  This question isn't about Libs being deserving, it is about why Cons seem to be intent on being unelectable.